# Use Save to drive button with an url from another domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-drive-api, cross-domain

I am trying to upload an image url from another domain with the Save to drive button of Google. So google tells me that I need to include the following special HTTP headers.

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Range
- Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Cache-Control, Content-Encoding,
  Content-Range

Do some one know how I can include this headers in my project?

I get this information from https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Save to Drive Demo: Basic Page</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="g-savetodrive"
     data-src="http://www.thehindu.com/multimedia/dynamic/02503/cat_2503938f.jpg"
     data-filename="Cat.jpg"
     data-sitename="My Company Name">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * on the server side to enable cross-domain communication; you may replace "*" with a specific domain so that only that domain will have access to the resource. The browser will put the Origin: (this is not controlled by the user), which is always required for a valid CORS request. When the server allows cross-domain communication, it will respond with the proper header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. After receiving the header, the browser send the data received from the server to the requesting XMLHttpRequest object. You have to take note of the browser you are using if it is capable of using CORS. Here is the [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) that will be helpful for using CORS which also includes a basic javascript for a CORS request.